# Dynamodb query/scan using python boto3

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

my dynamodb table has timestamp(in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MN:SS) as PrimaryKey column and temperature as sortkey while in data {"humidity" : 42 ,"location":"room" , "temperature":,"thermostat":}

in boto3 python i need to scan based on timestamp (now and 15min ago) with condition if difference(temperature - thermostat) > 5 for more than 10 times then return thermostat-5 and if (temperature - thermostat) < 5 for more than 10 times then returns thermostat+5... following is the code

```
import boto3
import math
import json
import time
import dateutil.tz
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
from dateutil import tz
from dateutil.tz import tzlocal
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    #table_name= "thermostat_dynamo"
    table_name= "TableDynamo"
    Primary_Column_Name = 'timestamp'
    table = dynamodb.Table(table_name)
    #key_param = "thermostat"
    #thermostatVal = table.get_item(Key={key_param:event[key_param]}) ## get record from dynamodb for this sensor
    thermostatVal= 77
    
    south = dateutil.tz.gettz('Asia/Kolkata')
   
    now = datetime.now(tz=south)
    fifteen_min_ago =  now - timedelta(seconds=900)
   
    now = now.strftime('%F %T')
    fifteen_min_ago = fifteen_min_ago.strftime('%F %T')
    
    fe = Key('timeStamp').between(fifteen_min_ago,now);
    response = table.scan(FilterExpression=fe & Attr('temperature').lt(thermostatVal))
  
    if response['Count'] == 10:
    #return thermostatVal+5 
        thermonew = thermostatVal + 5
        tosensor = '{"thermostat":'+ str(thermonew) + '}'
        print(tosensor)
        #response = client.publish(topic="updatehomesensor", qos=1, payload=tosensor)
        return

    elif response['Count'] < 10:
        print('{"thermostat":' + str(thermostatVal) + '}')
        return
```

Comment: show your work please

Comment: def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    fifteen_min_ago =  now - timedelta(seconds=900)
    now = now.strftime('%F %T')
    fifteen_min_ago = fifteen_min_ago.strftime('%F %T')
    fe = Key('timeStamp').between(fifteen_min_ago,now);
    response = table.scan(FilterExpression=fe & Attr('temperature').lt(thermostatVal))
    if response['Count'] == 10:
    thermonew = thermostatVal + 5
    tosensor = '{"thermostat":'+ str(thermonew) + '}'
    print(tosensor)     return
    elif response['Count'] < 10:
        print('{"thermostat":' + str(thermostatVal) + '}')
        return

Answer (score 0):

If `timestamp` was a sort key, you could have used a `Query` request to scan through all the items with timestamp > now-15min.

However, unfortunately, `timestamp` is your hash key. The only way you can find the items with timestamp > now-15min is to `Scan` through **all** your items. This will cost you a lot of money: You pay Amazon for each item scanned, **not** each item returned after the filtering.

Another problem is that the DynamoDB filtering syntax (look at the `FilterExpression` documentation) doesn't actually allow to do addition and subtractions as part of the test. If you always want to do "temperature - thermostat", you can use that as one of the attributes (so you can do a `FilterExpression` on it), and the second attribute would be "thermostat", and later you can add the two up to get the "temperature".

Comment: I am using following ... fe = Key('timeStamp').between(fifteen_min_ago,now);
    response = table.scan(FilterExpression=fe & Attr('temperature').lt(thermostatVal))    ... how to do temperature - thermostat with FilterExpression ?